# Parallel array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an assignment where we need to have 2 parallel arrays one is a list of city names and the other is sales amounts. Here is a copy of the problem:

**Program Description:**

It needs to compile sales totals for various cities in the USA. Specifically, when the program is run, the user will be prompted to enter a city. If the city is correct, the user will then be prompted to enter a sales amount. If the city doesn’t exist on the list, the user will get an error message (and no sales amount prompt). If a sales amount is entered, it will accumulate into a total for that city. Either way (city exists on the list or not) , the user will then be asked to enter another city or quit.
 Once the user quits, the city name and total should be displayed for all cities, one per line. Following that the program should stop.

There are only 8 cities to choose from.  2 parallel arrays must be used, initialized as follows:

```
City (String)  Sales (Integer)
-------------  ---------------
Atlanta              0
Buffalo              0
Chicago              0
Dallas               0
Houston              0
Honolulu             0
Miami                0
Reno                 0
```

All input is guaranteed to be single-word followed by enter only. It may not  match a city name, but there will be no spaces. This keeps your program simple as  it lets you avoid using getline( ), which would be needed to deal with blanks between words.
Sales data is guaranteed good when input.

When I attempted to run my program, visual studios went crazy, and I've pulled out my hair trying to fix it. If someone could help give me some pointers on what I've done wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is a copy of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare city and sales array
    string city[8] = {" "};
    int sales[8] = {0};

    //declare variables
    string cityName = " ";
    int cityTotal = 0;
    int salesAmt = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char another = ' ';

    //init city array
    city[0] = "Atlanta";
    city[1] = "Buffalo";
    city[2] = "Chicago";
    city[3] = "Dallas";
    city[4] = "Houston";
    city[5] = "Honololu";
    city[6] = "Miami";
    city[7] = "Reno";

    do
    {
        //input city name and if found input sales amount
        cout << "Enter a City: Atlanta, Buffalo, Chicago, Dallas, Houston, Honololu, Miami, or Reno: ";
        cin >> cityName;

        for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            if(cityName == city[i])
                {cout << "Enter sales amount: ";
                 cin >> salesAmt;
                 salesAmt += sales[i];}
            else
                {cout << "ERROR: CITY NOT AVAILIABLE" << endl;
                 cout << endl;}
            //end if
        }
        //end for loop

        //ask if another city
            cout << "Enter another city?: ";
            cin >> another;

    } //end do loop
    while(another == 'Y' || another == 'y');
    {
        for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            cout << "City: " << "           " << "Sales: " << endl;
            cout << city[i] << "          " << sales[i] << endl;
        }
        //end for loop
    } //end while loop

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //end of main
```

Comment: *visual studios went crazy*  That's all the description of the error? Try to be more specific.

Comment: `std::string` has well defined default constructor to initialize it with empty string. You don't need to initialize with `" "`

Comment: You should mark an answer sir.

Answer (score 6):

A clear error here is the way you have used the index to access the arrays, you can't have the for loop reach 8, as the array's index is only up to 7. change your for loops  to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //declare city and sales array
    string city[8] = {" "};
    int sales[8] = {0};

    //declare variables
    string cityName ="";
    int cityTotal = 0;
    int salesAmt = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char another = ' ';

    //init city array
    city[0] = "Atlanta";
    city[1] = "Buffalo";
    city[2] = "Chicago";
    city[3] = "Dallas";
    city[4] = "Houston";
    city[5] = "Honololu";
    city[6] = "Miami";
    city[7] = "Reno";

    do
    {
        //input city name and if found input sales amount
        cout << "Enter a City: Atlanta, Buffalo, Chicago, Dallas, Houston, Honololu, Miami, or Reno: ";
        cin >> cityName;

        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(cityName == city[i])
        {
            cout << "Enter sales amount: ";
             cin >> salesAmt;
             sales[i] += salesAmt;      
        } else if (i==7)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: CITY NOT AVAILIABLE" << endl;
        }//end if
    }//end for loop
        //ask if another city
            cout << "Enter another city?: ";
            cin >> another;

    } //end do loop
    while(another == 'Y' || another == 'y');
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            cout << "City: " << "           " << "Sales: " << endl;
            cout << city[i] << "          " << sales[i] << endl;
        }
        //end for loop
    } //end while loop

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //end of main
```

error was `for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++)` change with `for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)` and also second for.
Next error changed to `sales[i] += salesAmt;` and Not `salesAmt +=sales[i];`.

And your city name is `case sensitive` when you input city name!